# Connection refused while using debugger

Tags: node.js

I have attached a node debugger to my JS file and after attaching the debugger to the js file which is a server running on port 8080 while I try to access it using localhost - it gives the following error message:

The node version is v6.11.2 and the debugger which gets attached is the one comes with the node(default) like

```
node debug JSONServer.js
```

The module used in the file are core modules http and https and the OS of the machine is Windows 10

> connection refused

Please suggest what can be the reason.

Thanks

Comment: which node module?

Comment: We need more details of what you are using, `node-inspector` etc... maybe some snippets of code a print scrin will be helpfull etc..

Comment: The debugger which gets attached with node version v6.11.2 with the command node debug server.js

Answer (score 0):

All,

Later I tried running the debugger from Atom with the package [node-debugger](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger)

Still it gave same error

> Connection Refused

Then I tried to attach the debugger outside Atom with following command

```
node --debug=5858 JSONServer.js
```

And Opened the debugger in Atom and this time the Debugger worked in Atom.